# Detect data changes in database using listener

Tags: database, laravel, vue.js, vuex

I'm working on project with `Vue` and `laravel`. In each and ever components have more than one `http` requests when page is mounting, it's slowing things down and sometimes returns `500 error`. So i thought if the data is loaded and store in `Vuex store` and return when page load it'll be effective, but if the data inside the database changing while navigate through pages, data will not change re actively in pages. So is there a way to detect that change using javascript listners. Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting Basically once your backend code does the change to the DB you will need to broadcast that change to the front end.